# How do I set a member field to a value using codeDom namespace

Tags: c#, code-generation

Hi I want to create code that is something like this:

```
public string randomString = "some Random String";
```

How can i set a value to the member field that I created using:

```
CodeMemberField field = new CodeMemberField("System.String", "randomString");
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it on another stackoverflow question

```
field.InitExpression = new CodePrimitiveExpression("some Random String");
```